# Queue operator for RxJS

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

Is there an operator in RxJS that would allow me to buffer items and let them out one by one whenever a signal observable fires? Sort of like bufferWhen, but instead of dumping the whole buffer on each signal it would dump a certain number per signal. It could even dump the number that gets emitted by the signal observable.

```
Input observable:  >--a--b--c--d--|
Signal observable: >------1---1-1-|
Count in buffer:   !--1--21-2-121-|
Output observable: >------a---b-c-|
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip) to do what you want:

```js
const input = Rx.Observable.from(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]);
const signal = new Rx.Subject();
const output = Rx.Observable.zip(input, signal, (i, s) => i);
output.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
signal.next(1);
signal.next(1);
signal.next(1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

In fact, `zip` is used as an example in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1609) that pertains to buffering.

If you want to use the signal's emitted value to determine how many buffered values are to be released, you could do something like this:

```js
const input = Rx.Observable.from(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]);
const signal = new Rx.Subject();
const output = Rx.Observable.zip(
  input,
  signal.concatMap(count => Rx.Observable.range(0, count)),
  (i, s) => i
);
output.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
signal.next(1);
signal.next(2);
signal.next(1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`window` can be used to separate the timeline. And `takeLast` is used to hold the output.

```js
    let signal = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(4);

    let input = Rx.Observable.interval(300).take(10).share();

    let output = input
        .do(value => console.log(`input = ${value}`))
        .window(signal)
        .do(() => console.log(`*** signal : end OLD and start NEW subObservable`))
        .mergeMap(subObservable => {
            return subObservable.takeLast(100);
        })
        .share()

    output.subscribe(value => console.log(`    output = ${value}`));

    Rx.Observable.merge(input.mapTo(1), output.mapTo(-1))
        .scan((count, diff) => {
            return count + diff;
        }, 0)
        .subscribe(count => console.log(`            count = ${count}`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

**Result:**

```
22:28:37.971 *** signal : end OLD and start NEW subObservable  
22:28:38.289 input = 0  
22:28:38.292             count = 1  
22:28:38.575 input = 1  
22:28:38.576             count = 2  
22:28:38.914 input = 2  
22:28:38.915             count = 3  
            <signal received>
22:28:38.977     output = 0  
22:28:38.979             count = 2  
22:28:38.980     output = 1  
22:28:38.982             count = 1  
22:28:38.984     output = 2  
22:28:38.986             count = 0  
22:28:38.988 *** signal : end OLD and start NEW subObservable  
22:28:39.175 input = 3  
22:28:39.176             count = 1  
22:28:39.475 input = 4  
22:28:39.478             count = 2  
22:28:39.779 input = 5  
22:28:39.780             count = 3  
            <signal received>
22:28:39.984     output = 3  
22:28:39.985             count = 2  
22:28:39.986     output = 4  
22:28:39.988             count = 1  
22:28:39.989     output = 5  
22:28:39.990             count = 0  
22:28:39.992 *** signal : end OLD and start NEW subObservable  
22:28:40.075 input = 6  
22:28:40.077             count = 1  
22:28:40.377 input = 7  
22:28:40.378             count = 2  
22:28:40.678 input = 8  
22:28:40.680             count = 3  
22:28:40.987 input = 9  
22:28:40.990             count = 4  
            <input completed>
22:28:40.992     output = 6  
22:28:40.993             count = 3  
22:28:40.995     output = 7  
22:28:40.996             count = 2  
22:28:40.998     output = 8  
22:28:40.999             count = 1  
22:28:41.006     output = 9  
22:28:41.007             count = 0
```